# Set Global variables in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

What is the best way to add variables to Laravel framework that is accessible across Controllers and Views?

I don't want to use `.env` for storing the variables as it wouldn't be available via Git.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can create a file within `config` folder. e.g.

```
config
|- constants.php
```

Inside constants.php you can define your global variables

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Defined Variables
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is a set of variables that are made specific to this application
    | that are better placed here rather than in .env file.
    | Use config('your_key') to get the values.
    |
    */

    'company_name' => env('COMPANY_NAME','Acme Inc'),
    'company_email' => env('COMPANY_email','contact@acme.inc'),


];
```

You can access these variable using either of these two functions:

```
Config::get('constants.company_name')
config('constants.company_name')
```

For Blade as well:

```
{{ config('constants.company_email') }}
```

Comment: what if for example I want to retrieve additional user information on a separate table. how do i store the collection in a global variable?

Comment: @KimCarlo: I am not sure what you are exactly asking. Do you mean caching user information?

Comment: i'm not sure what the term is, but for example, I have a `user_details` table and it has a foreign key of `user_id`, and I query the table where `user_id` is equal to the id of authenticated user. I want to store the query result in a global variable so I can access it across all modules.

Comment: As asked in question, this way of storing details is for tracking info via Git. You may want to store these kinds of details in Cache or Session. Check docs for more details. I would recommend using Eloquent and setting relationships, so that you can Auth::user()->details. If it's not a lot of information, you don't need to store in session or Cache.

Comment: @KimCarlo You can create a separate class in App folder create static functions. Something like this: 
https://asperbrothers.com/blog/implement-repository-pattern-in-laravel/